# Agile User Stories and acceptance criteria

Tags: agile, user-story, acceptance-testing

I am writing some agile user stories and acceptance stories for the first time, and was hoping for some feedback from an experienced product manager or developer.

I only need to capture the main points in the acceptance criteria.

### User Story

AS A registered jobseeker, I WANT TO create and edit my CV on the user interface on my mobile device SO THAT employers and recruiters can view my career summary and contact details

### Acceptance Criteria

1. The user must sign into a registered account to create a CV
2. The user cannot save a CV unless all the mandatory fields on the form are complete
3. The user should be able to edit and delete the form at any time
4. Data from the saved form is stored in the CV database
5. Only registered Recruiters and Employers can view the users CV and contact details
6. The jobseekers user account is linked and synchronised on both mobile and desktop versions

Does this acceptance criteria sounds suitable for the given user story? Is there any way they can be more focused, and if so how?

Comment: Can you elaborate what kind of feedback you would like to receive? As it is, it is hard for us to tell if an answer would be useful.

Comment: Sure, I basically trying to come up with new features for a job seekers mobile app, and want to link some of the functionality to what already exist on the desktop version. Does that make sense?

Comment: @tobeeornot The only feedback I have is that the user story itself could probably be refined into two or more seperate stories.  I don't like to see conjunctions like `and` in a user story because it combines user needs.

Comment: @tobeeornot Actually you might like to take a look at [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196535/where-to-put-details-about-the-acceptance-criteria-of-a-user-story)

Comment: This is not a user story, this is an Epic, or maybe even just a product idea. It needs to be refined into multiple user stories, possibly clustered into multiple epics. By saying "just capture the main points" the client (or whoever said that) is making a classic requirements elicitation mistake, namely that the developer doesn't know what is required or nice-to-have unless he or she actually asks the client! As a developer, you should manage the requirements gathering process, not the client, and definitely not a non-technical person, because it is you who will be blamed if you missed a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is excellent. Your story makes sense, and you had a first shot at the acceptance criteria. Now, instead of checking it with this forum, check it with your team. Stimulate them to ask questions and extend the A.C. accordingly.

But since you specifically ask:

The Story:

- I would omit the "in the interface" from my user story.
- The story is potentially large. You could anticipate a split: (editing existing CV, creating new CV, viewing by recruiter).

The Acceptance criteria: If I were a team member at the planning meeting, I would ask more clarity about the following:

- It is not clear to me how the recruiters will view the CV. Is this also on a mobile device? Does this already exist? Otherwise the team will need more details about this.
- Which fields need to be implemented? Was this form already implemented in a web/desktop app? If so, then you can explicitly mention in your acceptance criteria that the mobile app should offer the exact same fields.
- Any data validation on these fields (eg. can I just enter "X" day of birth)

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback - the reason why I asked is that this is for an interview presentation and I don't have a development team to bounce off at this stage. Do you think it is ok for that?

Answer (score 1):

The story itself looks good and the first four acceptance criteria as well. They all relate directly to what the user is trying to accomplish with this story.

The last two acceptance criteria, I have my doubts about. They seem to belong to different stories (a story for Recruiters/Employers accessing the CV database and a story for using the service from both mobile and desktop environment).